# What route did Bnei Yisrael take through the Midbar? Seeking sources

Tags: sources-mekorot, geography, travel, yetziat-mitzrayim

The question of which route the Israelites took from Egypt to the Holy Land has been asked for centuries and discussed by pseudo-historians and pop-sci documentarians in the History Channel age, and it may be unanswerable in absolute terms.

But what do traditional Jewish sources say, if anything, on the subject?

**NOTE: AS INDICATED ABOVE, I'M WELL AWARE THAT AN ABSOLUTE ANSWER IS PROBABLY IMPOSSIBLE. I AM INTERESTED IN WHATEVER HAS BEEN SAID ABOUT IT, EVEN IF IT IS CONTRADICTORY.**

Comment: Whoa. <covers ears>

Comment: @double aa, travel, really?

Comment: @SethJ You can remove if you want. How else did they move from one place to the other?

Comment: This [chumash](http://www.nehora.com/products/Chumash-Meorot-Eynayim%252dShemos-----%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9-%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D%252d%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA.html) has a map on the last page with the route. Doesn't say though what they base it on.

Comment: Well, we get the list at the end of Sefer Bamidbar.  Are you asking how to match that up with geo-coordinates?

Comment: @Monica cellio Geo-coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

The sefer [הדורות מראש](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?143670) by Avraham Silber and published in 1959, has a 33 page essay on the subject including a hand drawn map. The book has the approbations of Rav Yaakov Kaminetzky and Rav Moshe Feinstein. The essay is written in Hebrew.
This is one of 18 essays on historical Biblical topics and they are quite fascinating.

Comment: What do the approbations say?

Comment: @DoubleAA You can read the first 40 pages [online](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?143670); the approbations are on page 11.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stations_of_the_Exodus

It's not much, but it pretty sums it up :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mi Yodeya.  We generally want answers to be more than just links.  Can you expand on this, perhaps quoting or summarizing some highlights of what it says there?  Thank you.